# Maximize a tricky function on $SU(n)$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization

Given non-zero $\xi \in \mathfrak{su}(n)$ and $G \in SU(n)$, consider the function:

$Q(U) = Tr(G^{\dagger}U)GU^{\dagger} - Tr(U^{\dagger}G) UG^{\dagger}$

(which just happens to be the gradient of $|Tr(UG^{\dagger})|^2$ right translated to the identity, and thus in $\mathfrak{su}(n)$).

What is $\max_{U} Tr(\xi^{\dagger}Q(U))$, and if possible the $U$ achieving this.